# WPF application has one more processes

Tags: wpf-controls

In my WPF application, used one graphics application as a control. But this graphics control/tool will run in separate process and WPF application is run in separate process. Problem is when i am navigating from one screen to some other screen, my WPF application window is minimized or going behind to other applications some times.

I want this problem to rectify. Please any give me solution for this.

Comment: Post some code, how exactly you are using your control in your code. Without that it's impossible to answer.

Comment: Alex, i cant share my code, Its confidential. In WPF, we are showing the  pages using DOCK control (XamDockManager). Navigating pages using PRISM Navigation framework. XamDockManager will divide the main page using SplitPane. In that one of Split pane is graphics control. The graphics control is Patron.